# How to put a little clickable cross on event in Fullcalender?

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

How can I put a little cross on event in fullcalender.

So that I click on it and perform an action.

Something like this:

[image]

Is it possible ?

My code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // ----- This Paramenter is Used for displaying Next,Previous,Today,Month,Week & Day ------ //  
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay',
            ignoreTimezone: false
        },
        selectable  : true,
        selectHelper: true,         
        editable    : true,
        firstDay    : 1,

        // ----- This Paramenter is Used for displaying Source Response ------ //   
        eventSources: [
                        'ajax/schedule_tasts.php',
                       ],

});
```

Comment: can you post your code ??

Comment: manipulate element in a render callback...http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventAfterRender/

Comment: @charlietfl Can you provide me a proper example ?

Comment: very basic example  http://plnkr.co/edit/UljZCB9A7GL9zPNIEvNC?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

This example is from **charlietfl**, it seems right, but to do what you want you need to add to each event a distinct attribute like an ID so when you click on it you know what event will take action. I modified this so you can click it.

```
  .eventButtons {
      background: #3498db;
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #3A87AD);
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #3A87AD);
      background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #3A87AD);
      background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #3A87AD);
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #3A87AD);
      -webkit-border-radius: 10;
      -moz-border-radius: 10;
      border-radius: 10px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #000000;
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #000000;
      box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #000000;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 12px;
      padding: 2px 8px 2px 8px;
      text-decoration: none;

    }

    .eventButtons:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
</style>
<script>
  $(function() {



    var events=[{
      id:1,
      title:'Simple event',
      start: new Date()
    }]

     $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
       events:events,
       eventAfterRender:function( event, element, view ) {

         element.append('<input class="eventButtons" type="button" value="X" name="button" onclick="alert()"/>')

       }
    })

});
</script>
```